# Simple task on Haskell, but do not know how this code works

Tags: haskell

I started to study Haskell. I found a code that, every few characters (which we set with a parameter), inserts a given character (also a parameter).
But I can't figure out how it works.

```
func1 :: [a] -> Int
func1 [] = 0
func1 (_:xs) = 1 + func1 xs

func2 :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
func2 _ [] = []
func2 n xs@(_:xs')
   | n > 0     = func2 (n-1) xs'
   | otherwise = xs

func3 :: [a] -> Int -> a -> [a]

func3 xs 0 y  = xs
func3 [] n y = []
func3 xs n y
 | func1 xs < n = xs
 | otherwise = n `take` xs ++ [y] ++ func3 (drop n xs) n y

main :: IO ()
main =  do
print(func3 "1234567" 2 '@')
```

I understand what, for example, this **func1 :: [a] -> Int** does, but what does this part of the code, I do not?

```
func2 n xs@(_:xs')
  | n > 0     = func2 (n-1) xs'
  | otherwise = xs
```

Or this one?

```
  func3 xs 0 y  = xs
  func3 [] n y = []
  func3 xs n y
   | func1 xs < n = xs
   | otherwise = n `take` xs ++ [y] ++ func3 (drop n xs) n y
```

Could you explain this to me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to go through the functions one by one.

`func1 xs` calculates the length of `xs`. `[]` has length `0`, and the length of `x : xs` is one more than the length of `xs`.

`func2 n xs@(_:xs')` is not called by any other function, but I will try to explain what it would do if it were called. The pattern `xs@(_:xs')` might seem unusual, so lets break it down. `xs@pat` binds the variable `xs` to the pattern `pat`. In this case, the pattern is `_:xs`. The underscore matches any value and discards it. `xs'` matches any list. If you called `func2 3 [1, 2]`, then this pattern would be matched. Inside the scope of the function, `xs` would be equal to `[1, 2]` and `xs'` would be equal to `[2]`. If `n > 0`, then `func2` calls itself, where `xs` has been replaced by the tail of `xs`, and `n` has been replaced by `n - 1`. This continues until `n = 0`, at which point `xs` is just kept.
Therefore, `func2 n xs` does essentially the same thing as `drop n xs`. At least as long as `length xs >= n`.

As you said, `func3` inserts `y` at every `n`th position of `xs`. There are several cases:
`n = 0` is an edge case with no obvious behaviour, so `func3` does nothing. If `xs = []`, there is no `n`th position in `xs` so `func3` again does nothing. The last pattern distinguishes two cases using guards. This is necessary because there are no patterns for "a list of length at least `n`", unless `n` is some constant known at compile-time. In the first case, the length of `xs` (calculated using `func1`) is less than `n`. Again, nothing to insert since there is no position `n`.
The second guard is where the magic happens. `otherwise` is literally just `True` and therefore this is a 'catch-all' guard. The result may be described by the following procedure: First we take the first `n` elements of `xs`. Then we append (`++`) the one-element list `[y]`. Then we append the result of `func2` applied to the remaining list.

This is the first time I posted an answer on SO, so feel free to ask if something was unclear!

Comment: Thanks for explaining